# Different splash screen on screen orientation

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I want to have different images on splash screen (same image in different sizes) in portrait and in landscape, in xamarin forms android application.
This is structure of my Resources folder:
[Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuOls.png)

And here is Splash screen:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", //Indicates the theme to use for this activity
         MainLauncher = true, //Set it as boot activity
         NoHistory = true, //Doesn't place it in back stack
         ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        this.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

I am always getting the image from drawable folder and then it is stretched in landscape. Does anyone has some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try Adding the Image you are using as splash screen in different resolution in to these different drawable folders  mdpi ,hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi

if that doesnt work try creating a background item with these properties

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:src="@drawable/AndroidSplashScreen"
 android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical" 
 />
```

but the best approach is use a 9-patch image or try using the latest vector image in android , Vector asset for your current image can be generated from the new version of android studio

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Where should i put bitmap property?

Comment: @sajidzahir my splashStyle.xml looks like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
 <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>`

Comment: Hi create another xml for the background and add the bitmap there now set this as the background


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:src="@drawable/AndroidSplashScreen"
 android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical" 
 />
  </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: This doesn't work. The application simply always seems to use the portrait version of the splashscreen. What changes are required to make sure that the app actually uses the images from the "-land" folder when starting the app in landscape mode?